# Vector as a 4x4 matrix

Tags: matrices

I need to multiply a 4x4 matrix with a 3x1 vector.

However, my program only supports 4x4 matrix being multiplied by another 4x4 matrix.

How do I represent my 3x1 vector as a 4x4 matrix so the multiplication works?

Comment: Ordinary matrix-vector multiplication would multiply a $4 \times 4$ matrix with a $4 \times 1$ vector (or on the other side a $1 \times 4$ vector.  How do you propose to define the product of a $4 \times 4$ with a $3 \times 1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had a $4 \times 1$ vector $v$ to go along with your $4 \times 4$ matrix $A$, I'd tell you to use the matrix $M_v = [v\ 0\ 0\ 0\ ]$, so that $AM_v = [Av\ 0\ 0\ 0]$.

But it just doesn't seem like a good idea to pad a vector with $3$ entries so that you can let a $4 \times 4$ matrix transform it (you could, just throw a $0$ entry somewhere in $v$ then use the trick above; but where would the $0$ belong?). There's a reason why the 'inner' dimensions of the matrices need to match up!

Can you expand on the question at all, to give some insight into why you have a dimension mismatch? It could be the case that there is a 'right' way to do what you're attempting.